# Inserting variables into URLs with bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, variables, curl

Say I want to write a bash script that takes user input, inserts it into a URL and then downloads it. Something like this: 
`#!/bin/bash`

cd /path/to/folder

echo Which version?

read version

curl -O http://assets.company.tld/$version/foo.bar

Would this work? If not, how can I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
version=$1
cd /path/to/folder
echo $version
curl -o $version-foo.bar http://assets.company.tld/$version/foo.bar
```

where `$1` is the first positional argument

So, suppose you save the script with name assets.sh. Then you can using the same like following:

```
./assests.sh ver1
```

where `ver1` is the version

[EDIT] If you want an interactive session:

```
#!/bin/bash
version=$1
cd /path/to/folder
echo -n "Which version you want? "
read version
curl -o $version-foo.bar http://assets.company.tld/$version/foo.bar
```

Comment: I actually want it to be interactive, as opposed to taking an argument -- the main question was "can I use a $variable in a call to cURL". Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Micha, I added the interactive script for the same purpose. See my EDIT.

Comment: The lack of quotes is a robustness problem. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)